# Trying to show datediff greater than ten days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a SQL statement, which calculates how many days a delivery of  undelivered products are delayed relative to the current date. The result should show the order number, order date, product number and the number of delay days for the order lines where the number of days of delay exceeds 10 days.

Here is my SQL statement so far:

```
SELECT 
    Orderhuvuden.ordernr, 
    orderdatum, 
    Orderrader.produktnr,
    datediff(day, orderdatum, isnull(utdatum, getdate())) as 'Delay days'
FROM 
    Orderhuvuden 
JOIN 
    Orderrader ON Orderhuvuden.ordernr = Orderrader.ordernr AND utdatum IS NULL
```

What I have a problem with is to solve how to show the delayed days that exceeds 10 days. I've tried to add something like:

```
WHERE (getdate() - orderdatum) > 10
```

But it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to solve this last step?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this to your where clause:

```
AND DATEDIFF(day, orderdatum, getdate()) > 10
```

Answer (score 3):

If the condition that you want is:

```
WHERE (getdate()-orderdatum) > 10
```

Simply rewrite this as:

```
WHERE orderdatum < getdate() - 10
```

Or:

```
WHERE orderdatum < dateadd(day, -10, getdate())
```

These are also "sargable" meaning than an index on `orderdatum` can be used for the query.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you need to add this to your WHERE clause.

```
datediff(day, orderdatum, isnull(utdatum, getdate())) > 10
```